# Extracting data by oid from DER encoded CMS message

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, asn.1

I have a CMS encoded message using DER format and want to extract data from the message by oid.

I have the following OpenSSL code that creates a CMS object and parses the message:

```
char message[] = "message.der"
BIO *in = BIO_new_file(message, "r");
CMS_ContentInfo *cms = d2i_CMS_bio(in, NULL);
```

I am unsure as to how to extract data relating to a specific oid?

Eg. data = foo(cms, "2.16.840.1.101.2.1.2.78.5");

Thanks.

Comment: Added language tags, C and C++

Comment: Do you have any comments on the actual content of the question regarding CMS structure? I change the language to C but either would've been fine.